# Settings ServerName and ServerAdmin in apache2.conf are not shown in PHP-Variables

Tags: php, apache2.4, fpm, server-variables, ubuntu-22.04

I was edit the apache2.conf and insert this Lines:

```
# Global configuration
#
ServerName server-16.******.de
ServerAdmin max.mustermann@******.de
```

But this values i can't see in the php variables if i look in phpinfo(). The results are:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN'] webmaster@localhost
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']  192.168.**.**
```

Why are the values not accepted?

Installed Software:
ubuntu 22.04 lts
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Apr 7 2022 17:46:26) FPM/FastCGI

thanks for support

Comment: Under Apache 2, you must set `UseCanonicalName On` in the configuration. In case you have a v-host that matches the root definition, you might check if there is a `ServerAdmin` set as well.

Comment: It worked. I thought on is the default value for UseCanonicalName. I was also able to solve the problem with ServerAdmin. The entry was overwritten in the configuration of the vHost. thx @guido-faecke